# Maintaining preprocessed data from large, continous data feed in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design, xml-parsing

I'm currently working on an analytics tool that every night (with a Java program) parses huge event logs (approx. 1 GB each) to a MySQL database - for each event there's about 40 attributes. The event logs are parsed "raw" to the database.

The user of the application needs to see different graphs and charts based on complicated calculations on the log data. For the user not to wait several minuts for a chart-request to be fulfilled, we need to store the preprocessed data somehow ready to display for the user (the user is able to filter by dates, units etc., but the largest parts of the calculations can be done on beforehand). My question is concerned about how to maintain such preprocessed data - currently, all calculations are expressed in SQL as we assume is the most efficient way (is this a correct assumption?). We need to be able to easily expand with new calculations for new charts, customer specific wishes etc.

Some kind of materialized view jumps to my mind, but MySQL doesn't seem to support this feature. Similarly, we could execute the SQL calculation each night after the event logs has been imported, but in this way each calculation/preprocessed data table needs to know which events it has processed and which it hasn't. The table will contain up to a year worth of data (i.e. events) so simply truncating the table and doing all calculations once again seems not to be the solution? Using triggers doesn't seem right neither, as some calculations need to consider for example the time difference between to specific kinds of events?

I'm having a hard time weighing the pros and cons of possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Materialized Views" are not directly supported by MySQL.  "Summary Tables" is another name for them in this context.  Yes, that is the technique to use.  You must create and maintain the summary table(s) yourself.  They would be updated either as you insert data into the 'Fact' table, or periodically through a cron job, or simply after uploading the nightly dump.

The details of such are far more than can be laid out in this forum, and the specific techniques that would work best for you involve many questions.  I have covered much of it in three blogs:  [DW](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse), [Summary Tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables), and [High speed ingestion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).  If you have further, more specific, questions, please open a new Question and I will dig into more details as needed.

I have done such in several projects; usually the performance is 10x better than reading the Fact table; in one extreme case, it was 1000x.  I always end up with UI-friendly "reports" coming from the Summary Table(s).

In some situations, you are actually better off building the Summary Tables and not saving the Fact rows in a table.  Optionally, you could simply keep the source file in case of a need to reprocess it.  Not building the Fact table will get the summary info to the end-user even faster.

If you are gathering data for a year, and then purging the 'old' data, see [my blog on partitioning](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).  I often use that on the Fact table, but rarely feel the need on a Summary Table, since the Summary table is much smaller (that is, not filling up disk).

One use case had a 1GB dump every hour.  A perl script moved the data to a Fact table, plus augmented 7 Summary Tables, in less than 10 minutes.  The system was also replicated, that added some extra challenges.  So, I can safely say that 1GB a *day* is not a problem.